# NReco multiple measures at run time

Tags: c#, dynamic, datatable, pivot-table, nreco

I am using the NReco library to build Pivot Tables. I'm following the examples and I was able to build a simple PvT from a DataSet. Now I want to build a PvT that receives a number of measures that are chosen at run time, but I'm having trouble with the dynamic nature of the process of using a list of measures each with it´s own formula of aggregation. The formula is known at run-time, and it's nothing more than a sum or an average, but is specific to the measure. I have the following code:

```
private string CreatePivotTable(DataTable dt, string[] lines, string[] columns, string[] dimensions, string measure)
    {

        var pivotData = new PivotData(dimensions, new SumAggregatorFactory(measure), new DataTableReader(dt));

        var pivotTable = new PivotTable(lines, columns, pivotData);
        var htmlResult = new StringWriter();
        var pvtHtmlWr = new PivotTableHtmlWriter(htmlResult);
        pvtHtmlWr.Write(pivotTable);

        return htmlResult.ToString();
    }
```

I wanted to do something like the following code to add the measures and the aggregator dynamically at run time:

```
 private string CreatePivotTable(DataTable dt, string[] lines, string[] columns, string[] dimensions, Measure[] measures)
    {


        var pivotData = new PivotData(dimensions, null, new DataTableReader(dt));

        foreach(var m in measures)
        {
            if (m.Formula.equals("sum"))
                pivotData.AggregatorFactory.Create(new SumAggregator(m.ColName));
            else if(m.Formula.equals("avg")){
             pivotData.AggregatorFactory.Create(new AvgAggregator(m.ColName));
           }
        }
     }
```

How can I achieve something like this? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `PivotData` class to collect several measures in the following way:

```
private string CreatePivotTable(
    DataTable dt, string[] lines, string[] columns, string[] dimensions, Measure[] measures)
{
    var aggrFactories = new List<IAggregatorFactory>();
    foreach(var m in measures) {
        if (m.Formula.equals("sum"))
            aggrFactories.Add( new SumAggregatorFactory(m.ColName));
        else if(m.Formula.equals("avg")){
            aggrFactories.Add( new AverageAggregatorFactory(m.ColName));
        }
    }
    if (aggrFactories.Length==0) {
        // no measures provided. 
        // Throw an exception or configure "default" measure (say, CountAggregatorFactory)
        aggrFactories.Add( new CountAggregatorFactory() );
    }   
    var pivotData = new PivotData(dimensions, 
        aggrFactories.Length==1 ? aggrFactories[0] : new CompositeAggregatorFactory(aggrFactories.ToArray()),
        new DataTableReader(dt));
    // you code that renders HTML pivot table with PivotTableHtmlWriter
}
```

As alternative you can use `PivotDataFactory` component (NReco.PivotData.Extensions assembly) that can create `PivotData` instance by `PivotDataConfiguration` model:

```
private string CreatePivotTable(DataTable dt, string[] lines, string[] columns, string[] dimensions, Measure[] measures)
{
    var pvtDataFactory = new PivotDataFactory();
    var pivotData = pvtDataFactory.Create( new PivotDataConfiguration() {
        Dimensions = dimensions,
        Aggregators = measures
            .Select(m => new AggregatorFactoryConfiguration(m.Formula, new[] {m.ColName}) )
            .ToArray()
    });
    // you code that renders HTML pivot table with PivotTableHtmlWriter
}
```

`PivotDataFactory` knows about standard aggregator types ("Count", "Sum", "Average", "Min", "Max") and if you use custom implementations you can register them with `PivotDataFactory.RegisterAggregator` method (see [Implement custom aggregator](https://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata/implement-custom-aggregator.aspx) for more details).

BTW real user-defined formula (that can use aggregator values as arguments) is also possible: see "DynamicFormulaMeasure" example from PivotData SDK examples package.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was having trouble  joining the pieces together through the NReco documentation, but I knew it was possible somehow. Keep up the good work Vitaliy, NReco is amazing and is saving me a lot of time!